# PHP recursive function having big static array

Tags: php, recursion

i got a crawler function like this:

```
function crawl_page($url) {
    static $j;
    echo "recur no:".++$j."\n";
    static $seen = array();

    if (isset($seen[$url]) ) {
        return;
    }

    $seen[$url] = true;

    // some more code


   foreach($links as $link) {
               $link .= '?start='.rand(1,300)*50; 
               crawl_page($link );
   }
   unset($links);
```

}

the script runs locally in console. the static array inside can be very large, thousands of elements, is it still the same data in memory, or is it copied when each new recursive call is done? after some 2000 or 3000 recurrences php process is much too big, over 1 GB large in memory and finally crashes. seems each recursion uses too large amount of memory. what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

### Do the test with a simple script

```
function func($iteration = 0) {
        if ($iteration++ == 3) return;
        print "\n$iteration\n";
        var_dump(memory_get_usage());
        static $var = array();
        var_dump(memory_get_usage());
        $var[] = str_repeat("byte", 100000);
        var_dump(memory_get_usage());
        func($iteration);
}

func();
```

gives:

```
1
int(632976)
int(632976)
int(1033232)

2
int(1033312)
int(1033312)
int(1433568)

3
int(1433648)
int(1433648)
int(1833904)
```

so, what do we see: memory usage only varies on insertion, but using `static $var;` doesn't really make a big change in memory.

### Conclusion

It must be simply your array size, temporary results etc. which let your memory exceed, but the static array only costs memory once (= it's not copied in every function call).

Comment: temporary results, this must be the cause. i got an object in the part of code not shown here, i forgot to unset after use. probably it has got instanciated many times. i am checking this out..

Comment: this function calls another database wrapper method. each that call i am loosing circa 1MB memory

Comment: this seems to be the reason, but without more code I cannot help ;-)

Comment: there are two calls inside. parsing functions and database wrapper object is created inside and then unset. too many code to paste here. but instead i would like to ask a general question. i think after leaving function all non static data should be destroyed, even if they are not unset explicitly. is that right? and here i see after return from the function (not returning any data) i am loosing 1MB. must be some fault? (i am using Zebra_Database class and Ganon parser)

Comment: @kurdt maybe some data is bound statically inside these classes etc… I don't know, maybe try to trace a bit where exactly the memory usage in the function changes by adding memory_get_usage() calls before and after each statement. I really can't help without any code; just do a few wild guesses…

Comment: after tracig i have found memory leak. it is Ganon parser. great tool, but memory leaking is known issue to it.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the code I'm a little puzzled about:

```
 $link .= '?start='.rand(1,300)*50;
```

This will make multiple versions of each link. If one of those pages uses it's own link to make a link to itself you have yourself an infinite loop:

```
$link == '/', result: self: '/', crawl_page('/?start=50');
$link == '/?start=50', self: '/?start=50', result: crawl_page('/?start=50?start=200');
...
```

It can also be that the number of pages multiplied by the average of hitting one number between 0 and 299 twice exhausts the memory by having too many elements in your array.

Comment: @kurdt I know, but do you your code remove possible query strings in the links?